# SharePoint 2007: How to upload multiple files to a List Item?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, file-upload

I know that a Document Library in SharePoint 2007 has a multi-file uploader (an ActiveX control that -- and only if you have Office 2003+ installed) but how would I use this same feature with a normal (non-document-library) List item?

Uploading files to a normal List item involves clicking the "upload" link and browsing/uploading files one by one. Is there a better way than this? Surely there must be.

Jake

Answer (score 2):

There is an approach I use, but there is no UI support for it. You may find it a bit tedious for onsey-twosey uploads, but it saved me hours once for serious bulk uploads.

The same WebDAV functionality that we get when using "Open with Windows Explorer" on a document library is available for a list.

Say I have a list at `http://myorg.com/sites/Widgets/Lists/MyList`.

I can open the list in Windows Explorer by going to the address `\\myorg.com\sites\Widgets\Lists\MyList`.

Attachments are stored in the sub-folder `Attachments`, which contains folders with numeric names (1, 2, 3, ... and so on). The numbers correspond to the item ID of the list item. Pick (or create) a folder with the ID corresponding to the item you want to upload to, and it's drag-and-drop from there.

Comment: Nice - I'll have to remember that next time someone here wants to add a stupid number of attachments to a list item. I'm not sure I liek the idea of all our users being able to mess about with the list forms though.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing your own mulit-file upload web part I think you are going to be stuck with either one at a time (i.e. an attachment to the list item) or switch to a document library. Don't forget that you can customise your library to behave much like a list.

Why is it a problem to use a document library?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm fairly new to SharePoint. I didn't realise I could do it the way you're suggesting and will look in to it some more. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'm stuck. How would I go about customising a library to behave like a list? They seem quite different to me and I can't see how the library can act like what I've got the List to do.

Comment: What is it you have achieved with the list that you can't with the library?

Comment: In a library you can bulk upload but if you need to put text in a field like you do in a list, you are stuck with 255 Characters. That's what's wrong with a library.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be making a habit of answering my own questions. Not sure if that's a good thing or not.

What I ended up doing was adding an "Upload Multiple Files" button to the toolbar which pointed to a custom ASPX page in the _layouts folder. This page displayed the ActiveX component used by a Document Library and the "post to" URL for it was the ASPX page itself. When posted to it looked for files uploaded and attached them all to the List Item referenced via URL parameters passed to it from the toolbar button.

It's discussed here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nathanyorke/archive/2007/12/05/uploading-multiple-files-via-the-web.aspx

If I get round to blogging and fuller explanation on my own site I'll try and remember to post a link back here.

Jake